# SATA III PCI-E controller card hangs installers / live CD

Tags: linux, motherboard, sata, pci-express, disk-controller

This is a long shot, but figured I'd ask here to see if anyone has a solution to my problem.

I was wanting to put together an inexpensive file server, so I picked up an ECS motherboard that has an on board AMD processor ( KBN-I/2100 (V1.1) ).
http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1499&MenuID=106&LanID=0

It has an PCI-Express slot that I was hoping to use with a SATA III PCI-E controller card. I picked up one that identifies itself at system boot as Asmedia 106X SATA Controller. I have two seagate 2TB drives connected to it, that also appear to be correctly displayed as well on that splash screen.
https://goo.gl/photos/f3onopR1sf8GztAt5

Is there a good reason why this card wouldn't work with this motherboard, or is this slot really not intended for such a device?

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to shed some light on this problem!

Comment: any PCI-E equal to or greater than the card you are installing works.  Your motherboard **may not** support booting from an external controller.  You might want to try installing the OS on a USB stick and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did install Debian on a drive connected to the first on-board SATA port on the motherboard, and it seems to boot just fine with the controller installed. The un-populated SATA controller appears as a valid SATA controller ( lspci lists it as "01:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)" ) 

I tried booting SystemRescueCD with both drives connected, and it just hangs. I haven't tried installing a more full-blown linux install to another  drive, but the Debian installer hangs as well when booting with the populated controller